# Dynamically create random number of dropdownlists in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I need to create a random number of dropdownlists in my view, based on the selected value of another dropdownlist. This is all done but my problem comes when I need to make the httppost because i never know how much data i need to save in my db.

In my model I have a list

```
public List<RoomToBooking> RoomsToBooking { get; set; }
```

that will get filled with x number of RoomToBooking when the Create view is rendered after the user makes a selction of dropdownlist 1:

```
var dogs = from d in db.Dogs
                       where d.Customer_ID == id
                       select d;
            foreach (Dog item in dogs)
            {
                roomToBooking = new RoomToBooking();
                roomToBooking.Customer_ID = id;
                roomToBooking.Dog = item;
                roomsToBookingList.Add(roomToBooking);
            }
```

So I would like to create the same number of dropdownlist in my Create view

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Booking.RoomToBooking, new SelectList(ViewBag.DeliveryTypes), new { @class = "selectbox" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Booking.RoomToBooking)
```

So I in the end can be able to save it to my db

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(EditBookingPensionViewModel model)
    {
        foreach (RoomToBooking item in objViewModel.RoomsToBooking)
        {
            //Save to db
        }            
    }
```

I assume that I should use jquery to create the dropdownlists, but how do i create the dropdownlists so the selected values can be found in my viewmodel??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may take a look at the [following article](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/). I slight adaption might be necessary for your scenario because you don't have add and remove buttons but instead you use the selected value of a dropdownlist to determine the number of dynamic rows to be added. But the concept is the exactly the same.